# Too many arguments, expected arguments "command"

Tags: magento2.4, install-script

[image]

Hi, can anyone help to identify how to fix this? I am installing from a Magento 2.4 Script onto ubuntu 20.04.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide us the entire command which you executed? Edit your question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible you forgot some flag.

Try with this command:

```
bin/magento setup:install --backend-frontname="admin" \
--db-host="localhost" \
--db-name="database_name" \
--db-user="username" \
--db-password="password" \
--language="en_US" \
--currency="GBP" \
--timezone="Europe/London" \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--use-secure=0 \
--base-url="http://www.magentourlbase.com" \
--base-url-secure="https://www.magentourlbase.com" \
--admin-user=adminuser \
--admin-password=123123q \
--admin-email=admin@magentourlbase.com \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=user \
--cleanup-database
```

Comment: I tried this and this is what's coming up - SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'simon'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

In InstallCommand.php line 274:

  Parameter validation failed

Comment: Got it installed, thank you!! It seems to be taking a long time to get the authentication email through is this normal?

Comment: Be sure of the email service is working. If you are in a local environment and want to log in into the admin area, i recommend you to disable the `Magento_TwoFactorAuth` module, running: `bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth && bin/magento se:up` in order to sign in without 2f validation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I used a password which is not supported by the setup install command.

My password was like "company!!", I had to remove the `!!`. I replaced it with `company11` and now it works.